# How to use a Letterpack?

Tags: edit-mode

I just downloaded my first letterpack, but I don't know how to use it.
Do I have to move the wanted letters to another layer or copy them to another project and if so, how?

Comment: What specifically are you stuck at?

Answer (score 1):

I found it, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and than paste it in another one with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.